# Speed data logging using arduino and GPS module

Tags: arduino-uno, gps, speed

I am using a Quectel L80-R GPS Module coupled with an Arduino UNO to read and log my car's coordinates and speed. I am currently using TinyGPS++ library which works okay. It does spell out coordinates and speed but with some inaccuracies and delays. After some literature review I realized that NeoGPS library might be a better option. I found a [thread](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22873/neo-6m-gps-speed) over stackexchange where a code block is provided written by [slash-dev](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/14737/slash-dev) who most possibly is the writer of NeoGPS library. However, when I am trying to compile the code, I get the following error
`'class gps_fix' has no member named 'lat'` .I can not get rid of the issue even tough I've tried a whole bunch of workarounds.

Comment: Have you looked at the NeoGPS library source code or one of the examples that come with the library to see what class members *are* available with `gps_fix`?

Comment: Looking at [this documentation](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/extras/doc/Data%20Model.md) you might need `fix.latitudeL()` and `fix.longitudeL()` instead of `fix.lat` and `fix.lon`.

Comment: I was under the impression that latitude, longitude & speed (and many other values) were products of the GPS module.  Software like TinyGPS and NeoGPS mostly just configure the GPS module and parse the data stream.  What do you mean by inaccuracies and delays?  On a good day, a cheap (uncorrected) GPS module should be about +/- 10 meters latitude and longitude.  And much worse (maybe 5 to 10 times as bad) for altitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [NeoGPS documentation for the gps_fix class](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/extras/doc/Data%20Model.md), it looks like `.lat` and `.lon` are no longer part of the `gps_fix` class.

It looks like instead you will have to use `.latitudeL` and `.longitudeL` for high precision (Long Integer scaled by 10,000,000) GPS coordinates.

The solution would be to replace `fix.lat` in your code with `fix.latitudeL` and `fix.lon` with `fix.longitudeL`.